# Open a .PDF located in WebDAV directly into Acrobat (or default PDF app.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, activex, webdav

I have a PDF in a webDAV Server and when it comes down to Opening the document, as I would any other Word or Office Document, after it asks me If I would like to open the file it just hangs and then the script times out. I can see that the script is trying to Open Microsoft Word 2010, since I am using Sharepoint.OpenDocuments and the FFWinPlugin to allow .DOC's to be opened. But what do I do in the case of .PDF's ? Are there any Adobe Active X controls that allow me to work with PDF's (In the case of IE Explorer), and what about Firefox and Chrome (which dont use ActiveX) ??

I am desperately looking for any information regarding webDAV and its handling of PDF documents.

@ITHitWebDAV

Comment: @ITHitWebDAV What do I need to use in order to Open .PDF's with WebDAV directly from a browser? I am at a loss!

Comment: @ITHitWebDAV I use this script to open Word documents, is there one that is similar, but for PDF's?: http://pastebin.com/34sNSWeL

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way for you to set the `Content-Type` header that's returned by the WebDAV server? IIRC, the IE Adobe Reader plug-in looks for that. In the Windows registry, the file extension `pdf` has a `Content-Type` of `application/pdf`. This should also work for other browsers.

Comment: Is there a way I can check the Content-Type that is being used beit through a browser, or programmatically? In the method I was using to download the file I added a parameter for the `HttpReponse` and in the method I added code that assigns content type `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"` and doing what I believe to be the correct procedure to send this information back client side by then calling `Response.Flush()` and `Response.End()` respectively. Am I on the right track? Gonna test this out now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can use Fiddler (a free tool now by Telerik) to check out all the interactions between your web browser and any web server. Also, yes, that seems correct to me setting the `Response.ContentType`. That's exactly what I'm talking about above :)  I hope it works for you.

Comment: Well, this didn't end up working. I am not sure where exactly I would have to specify the Response's Content-Type. Also I am not even sure if I can set the content-type for the webDAV Server through my page? I am hoping @ITHitWebDAV will get back to me on the matter soon. Seeing as that their AjaxFileBrowser lets me edit a PDF file from their demo.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't work. I'm also not sure that you can set that header when using WebDAV. Honestly, I'm not extremely familiar with WebDAV, but my suggestion struck me as something that might help. I'll see what I might be able to dig up for you.

Comment: Nonetheless, thank you for your suggestion of a possible solution. Any help is always appreciated by me. Utilizing Fiddler I noticed that the request being sent is of Content-Type `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`, but this is a querystring which opens an .aspx I use to handle the displaying or downloading of files (I send the necessary info in the query string and the .aspx has a method which in turn handles the downloading/fetching of the item.), so I am not sure if it is supposed to be that Content-Type or not. But either way thank you for your input!

Comment: Ah. I've seen sites that use an ASPX or ASHX page to handle sending back non-HTML data. It can sometimes cause havoc. I do seem to remember something about a `Content-Disposition` header. Try doing some research on that. I'll take a further look if I have some time. That may only be for file uploading, though, and not downloading--but I really can't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments or PdfFile.OpenDocuments ActiveX control. This components are mentioned in [Enterprise Administration Guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/planning.html) from Adobe in section 3.4.

It says that:

> The ActiveX control AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments is installed on the
>   client computer with Acrobat X or Reader X.

Comment: Thanks for the Response ITHit. I still don't understand how I am supposed to load this into my code? Does this interact with javascript? Is there an object I load up? I am so confused as to how you guys accomplish it on the ajaxbrowser! Thank you for the information and your time.

Comment: I am really confused because you guys manage to do this in your Ajax Browser for your webDAV Server -  http://www.ajaxbrowser.com/ . If you upload a PDF to the browser and then right click, click edit file... It will open up in your reader and save any changes made to editable fields (if any). From what I have read from the resources you have provided the AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments ActiveX control is for use with Sharepoint Servers. No talk about how to manipulate it programmatically. Please help guys!

Comment: Still waiting for a response on this inquiry guys? Please help out a customer!

Answer (score 0):

For archival purposes and other people trying the above solutions, I could not get them to work. I too want to open a PDF from an Apache WebDAV server straight into Adobe Reader on Windows 8 and IE 11. I've installed Adobe Reader XI v11.0.06.
I modified the code linked on paste bin in the second comment of first post to use the AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments ActiveX or if it fails the PdfFile.OpenDocuments ActiveX.
Adobe Reader is started after some security messages from IE, connects to the provided WebDAV url, but after entering my login details alerts me by saying that it cannot open the PDF possibly because of improper path / file name syntax or drive specification.
Opening the same URL via the open dialog in Adobe Reader works perfectly, so it can to my opinion not be wrong syntax.
The same alert box is given when opening Adobe Reader with the WebDAV url from the command line, although local files are opened perfectly fine.
Maybe has something to do with the open dialog being able to use the windows webclient to open WebDAV locations? Command line and ActiveX modules logically do not have this functionality available without additional programming by Adobe.

Comment: MaGaM, what I found out after de-compiling ITHits code was that they created completely custom functions for their handling of the PDF files. I definitely could have implemented something to edit the PDF's on the fly, but it would of taken a lot of coding to do something similar to ITHits very well rounded implementation. In the end this project was dead in the water and so further research/dev into the project was unecessary.

Answer (score 0):

ActivX **SharePoint.OpenDocuments** works for me

```
new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments").EditDocument('utl to a document')
```

Comment: What would be the approach using Edge?